# Верстка по вертикали в резиновой верстке

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, вёрстка

Каким образом можно задать резиновую верстке по вертикали в процентном соотношении, заранее не зная высот блоков?

Comment: В процентном отношении к чему? (высота браузера, ширина браузера, ширина родителя, размера шрифта....)

Answer (score -1):

использовать единицы измерения `vh` для высот/отступов/позиций элементов

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/615008)

Comment: какой вопрос - такой ответ, ИМХО, дающий нужную информацию.

Comment: Даже твое  `ИМХО` является неверным....

Comment: Обоснуйте, пожалуйста.